# I want to know about ttl time

Tags: windows-7, ping, ttls

172.16.0.1: bytes=32 time=18 TTL-61
Suppose this is my ping test 
here time=18,   >18 is better or <18 is better 
and what is the optimal ttl time should be?

Answer (score 2):

**Ping Time**

> Ping measures Round Trip Time (RTT), records any packet loss, and prints when finished a statistical summary of the echo response packets received, the
>   minimum, mean, max and in some versions the standard deviation of the round trip time.

A lower value for Ping Time is better.

**Time To Live (TTL)**

There is no optimum value for TTL.

- TTL or Time To Live is an integer value between 0 and 255. It specifies the number of router hops a packet is allowed to travel before it must be discarded or returned.
- TTL is sometimes used as a hop count limit and other times as a time limit. The hop count function is critical to network functionality. It ensures that packets do not looping infinitely in a network. The time limit function is used by transport protocols such as TCP to ensure reliable data transfer.
- Each router that handles a packet MUST decrement the TTL by at least one, even if the elapsed time was much less than a second. Time-to-Live functions as a hop count in this perspective. Since this is the case most of the time, TTL is effectively a hop count limit on how far a datagram can propagate through the Internet.
- When a router forwards a packet, it MUST reduce the TTL by at least one. If it holds a packet for more than one second, it MAY decrement the TTL by one for each second. In this way, TTL is used as a time count.
- When TTL gets to zero, the router discards the IP Packet and an ICMP "TTL Expired in transit" message is sent back to the sending IP Address.
- Ping, Tracert, and Pathping all make use of the TTL value to attempt to reach a target host or to trace a route to that host.
- TTL has been renamed renamed "Hop Limit" in IPv6. It ha the same function as TTL in IPv4.

Answer (score 0):

TTL Time To Live, this means the maximum amount of hops the packet can make before it is dropped.

On the ping time the lower the better as this means you have a short and/or fast round trip for the packet